# PHP. Сортировка в строке

Tags: php, строки

Есть строка со словами $words = "animal,people,cats,mack,apple,juice,mouse,marvel,keyboard,beer,drug,gun."; Слова разделены запятыми, в конце точка. Нужно найти самое длинное и самое короткое слово (то есть keyboard и gun) и сделать из них словосочетание, то есть keyboardgun.
Сделал так, но оно сортирует по алфавиту:

```
    <?

$words = "animal,people,cats,mack,apple,juice,mouse,marvel,keyboard,beer,drug,gun.";
echo "Words is: $words";
$words = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1251', $words);
$words = explode(',', trim($words, '.'));
sort($words);
$words = implode(',', $words) . '.';
$words = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $words);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
echo "After changing, my string is: ";
print_r("<b>$words</b>");
    ?>
```

Comment: [Дубликат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055942/php-%d0%9e%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "animal,people,cats,mack,apple,juice,mouse,marvel,keyboard,beer,drug,gun.";

$words = explode(',', trim($string, '.'));
$min = $max = 0;
$result = [];

foreach ($words as $word) {
    $length = strlen($word);

    if ($length > $max) {
        $result[0] = $word;
        $min = $max = $length;
    }

    if ($length < $min) {
        $result[1] = $word;
        $min = $length;
    }
}

echo join($result);
```